# vertical-align text within a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css, textarea

I have

```
<html>
<textarea id='txt' style='height:500px; widht:400px'></textarea>
<input type='text' id='input'/>
<input type='button' id='clicMe' onkeypress='fillTxt()' />

<script>
function fillTxt(){
  if(event.keyCode == 13)
      document.getElementById('txt').value += document.getElementById('input').value + <br/>;
}
</script>
</html>
```

what I want is that the when I click on the button the text gets inside the textarea and be vertically aligned bottom. Meaning the text I add will append to the bottom of the textarea

Example:

```
.-----------------------------.
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
|  this is some text          |
'-----------------------------'
```

### EDIT:

I got it working now

```
<div id="tBox" style=" 
    position:absolute;
    top:400px;
    left:220px;
    width:600px;
    height:334px;
    color:#666666;
    padding:5px;
    margin-bottom:25px;">

        <div id="tHolder" style="
            width:500px; 
            height:300px; 
            background-color:transparent; 
            color:#008080; 
            font-weight:bold; 
            border-style:hidden; 
            left:5px; 
            background-color:transparent;
            position:relative;
            overflow:auto;">

            <p id="txt" style='position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0;'></p>

        </div>

        <input type="text" style="width:500px; position:absolute; bottom:15px; left:8px;" id="input" name="input" onkeydown="fillTxt()" />

</div>
```

Comment: Note that there is a difference in a text that is vertically aligned to the bottom, and a text that is simply placed at the bottom of a textbox. In the case of an align, the text at the bottom would still mark the beginning of the textbox's value, and any new text being entered would push the value up. In the case of text at the bottom of the textbox, you would be able to place the caret above this text, and start writing text that would push the text down. Is the former really what you want?

Comment: Maybe you let us know what your reason is so we can suggest better alternatives since as David points out, align is not possible but insertion of blank lines are.

Comment: I edited my input for the working code ... thanks for the help yall

Answer (score 9):

you actually have 2 options and both of them are not "natural" in the sense that we are creating things that normally they don't do (but hey, who doesn't?)

the first one is a content editable `<p>` tag aligned to stick to the bottom of a container `<div>`. I prefer this one since you just have elements that act like textboxes. you have select and the ability to land the cursor anywhere:

```css
 #contentEditableDiv{
        width:300px;
        height:200px;
        margin:100px auto;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background:#EEE;
        position:relative;
        overflow:auto;
    }
    
    #editableP{
        background:red;
        min-height:10px;
        position:absolute;   
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="contentEditableDiv">
        <p id="editableP" contentEditable="true"></p>
    </div>
```

another option is to have a div as a placeholder for the style, and have a hidden textarea sync with it. this needs a bit more logic to imitate a true textbox but this is just the concept:

```js
window.onload = (function(){
    
        var textArea = document.getElementById('textArea');
        var hiddenTextArea = document.getElementById('hiddenTextArea');
        var textHolder = document.getElementById('textHolder');
        
        textArea.addEventListener('click',function(){
            hiddenTextArea.focus();
        },false);
        
        hiddenTextArea.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
            textHolder.innerHTML = hiddenTextArea.value;
        },false);
    
    
    }());
```

```css
#textArea{
        width:300px;
        height:200px;
        margin:100px auto;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        background:#EEE;
        position:relative;
        overflow:auto;
    }
    #textHolder{
     position:absolute;   
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
    }
```

```html
<div id="textArea">
        <span id="textHolder"></span>
    </div>
    <textarea id="hiddenTextArea"></textarea>​
```

Comment: Unfortunately, if you want to be notified when the content is updated, the _input_ event does not work for _contenteditable_ elements in IE.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is possible, (to enter text at the bottom of the textarea).

Your best bet might be to define the number of rows in the textarea, (say height: 5em; line-height: 1em;), and then use javascript to add 4 linefeeds before your input text.

That or just have the textbox 1 row high, and pad it on the top to make it look like there are empty rows above.

Answer (score 0):

This is something not possible through CSS. You might need JS code to determine height of textarea and add padding accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually you could add a text field in a div and set the distance between in the div and top of the textarea, and the bottom of the div and the bottom of the textarea.

Somehow you could auto hight the textarea, then it should work.

Answer (score -1):

Hi i thing you should give padding to textarea as like this

```
    textarea{
width:400px;
    height:400px;
    padding-top:100px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
     -o-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[link here if you check live](http://jsfiddle.net/L5TJL/)

http://jsfiddle.net/L5TJL/

Comment: that works if I need the text to only appear in the area of 300px below the top border. what i want is for the text to first appear at the bottom and then additional text append to the bottom