# How to begin typing from vertical middle of textarea

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have a textarea, like this

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
```

In default the cursor will start from the top left of the textarea, But i want it to be started from **vertical and horizontal center** of textarea like text aligned to middle in a table-cell.

I have achieved horizontal center by applying `text-align:center`, But how to make it vertically center?

Something like this:

[image]

It should be like this if more text is entered.

[image]

I tried this CSS:

```
textarea {
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: what should happen when the next line is reached? should the entered text go up or down?

Comment: I don't think it's possible but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903057/vertical-align-text-within-a-textarea) may give you a few ideas for a work around

Comment: @epoch the whole typed text should position vertically center

Comment: sorry if i'm being dumb in this regard, but that does not make sense, wouldn't a padding top and bottom achieve exactly the same thing then? see the following: http://jsfiddle.net/gy5Cf/1/

Comment: @epoch padding-bottom will not push the text to top while we enter more text

Comment: What browsers do you want to make it work in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot think of a way to do this with just `<textarea>` but I have a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Jv6tW/) that almost works using a [`contenteditable`](http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/) `<div>`. From that article:

> Browser support for contenteditable is surprisingly good

The only problem I see is when the text fills the vertical space the `<div>` expands. I cannot think of any way to stop this in `CSS` (and I tried many different properties!). It should be possible to intercept this in JavaScript and stop the `<div>` expanding.

**HTML**

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    height:150px;
    width:350px;
    border:1px solid black;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: seems a better way to achieve the situation. Need a check with my `<form>` whether i can submit this along with other form elements.

Comment: You will probably need to copy the text into a hidden `<textarea>` to submit as part of a `<form>`

Comment: So, i think this will do the job for me, Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

you have to following code for css.

```
<style>
textarea {
    text-align:center;
    padding:50px 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
     -o-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    display:inline-block;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Sorry, this will not do the job

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I **[fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/epoch/gy5Cf/3/)** around a bit, and came up with a solution immitating what you need, it is a div with a textarea inside:

**HTML**

```
<div id="expandedText">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div#expandedText {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;

    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 50px 10px 40px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;

    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

div#expandedText > textarea {
    width: 250px;
    height: 50px;

    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    resize: none;

    outline: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: But when typing a little more the top lines gets hidden out, what i want is when typing more the previous lines should move to top keeping equal top and bottom spacing.