# How do I set the cursor to be the bottom of a textarea and text will go up as user types?

Tags: html, css, textarea, styling

Hi I am trying to create a textarea similiar to the following:

[image]

I can do the styling for the textarea, but is there a way to set the user to start **typing from the bottom of the textarea**, and **the text will go up everytime they press enter**, reverse from the normal textarea where you type from top to down.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot alter this default behavior of the text area. However you can use some text inputs and text areas to create an element that behave as you want.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903057/vertical-align-text-within-a-textarea) question for further details.